# Array Adapter NotifyDataSetChanged() NullPointerException Android

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-adapter

I am adding a map to a list and then refreshing the array adapter. This was working perfectly earlier, but now that I am using an addItem() method from two different methods, it throws a NullPointer. I hope my code will clear up what I am saying:

```
SimpleAdapter adapter;
List<HashMap<String, String>> painItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
ListView listthings;
int[] to;
String[] from;
String painLevelString, timeOfPainString, textTreatmentString,
        painLocation, row1, row2, name;

OnCreate(){
 if(getIntent().getStringExtra("newPainLevel")!= null){
        createNewEditedEntry();

        }
     adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, painItems, R.layout.mylistlayout,
            from, to);
    listthings.setAdapter(adapter);
}

 private void createNewEditedEntry() {
    String newPainLevel = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("newPainLevel");
    String newPainTime =this.getIntent().getStringExtra("newPainTime");
    String newTreatment =this.getIntent().getStringExtra("newTreatment");
    painLevelString = newPainLevel;
    timeOfPainString = newPainTime;
    textTreatmentString = newTreatment;
    row1 = "sample1";
    row2 = "sample2";

    addItem();
    //painItems.remove(getIntent().getStringExtra("position"));
    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

 }

@Override
// on the activityresult,get the string extra, then add the item to the list
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == 1) {
        row1 = data.getStringExtra("com.painLogger.row1");
        row2 = data.getStringExtra("com.painLogger.row2");


        painLevelString = data.getStringExtra("com.painLogger.painLevel");
        painLocation = data.getStringExtra("painLocation");
        timeOfPainString = data.getStringExtra("com.painLogger.painTime");
        textTreatmentString = data
                .getStringExtra("com.painLogger.treatment");
        addItem();
    }
}

// to add the item, put it in the map, and add the map into the list
private void addItem() {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("row_1", row1);
    map.put("row_2", row2);
    map.put("row_3", painLevelString);
    map.put("row_4", painLocation);
    map.put("row_5", timeOfPainString);
    map.put("row_6",textTreatmentString);
    painItems.add(map);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //Null Pointer **HERE**
    }
```

Just to be clear, createNewEditedEntry() and onActivityResult() are never called at the same time and never clash. They are two completely different occurrences. It was working with just the OnActivityResult, but now when I use CreateNewEditedEntry(), it has stopped working. I have also checked and made sure that none of the Strings that I fetch from my intent are null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize `adapter`  before you call `createNewEditedEntry` in `onCreate`:

```
OnCreate(){
     adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, painItems, R.layout.mylistlayout, from, to);
      if(getIntent().getStringExtra("newPainLevel")!= null){
        createNewEditedEntry();    
      }
// ...
}
```

Otherwise, `adapter` will be null in `addItem` called from there (last line of `createNewEditedEntry`).

Comment: thank you for responding so quickly! I cannot accept the answer yet(It will not let me for another 3 minutes), but I think it fixed it(I am encountering yet another(unrelated) error).

Answer (score 0):

You should also be aware that your call to addItem can fail if your activity was destroyed by Android while you were in the sub-activity. Have a read of my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275845/getting-nullpointerexception-with-contentprovideroperation) to understand what can happen when resources get low.